# which browsers dont send the referer header?

Tags: html, http, browser, http-referer

I always read about the fact, that user-agents dont have to send the referer header so you cant rely on it. To limit others from "stealing" pictures from your page and generating extra load for you without gaining anything from that, using the referer to check if the user was on your page is the only way to circumvent the stealing (there are other techniques like sessions but require cookies).

so i was wondering if anybody has some data/numbers on the distribution of user-agents that omit the referer header?!